# How to get the first match in regexp?

Tags: regex

I have three strings as list below:

```
Levofloxacin 500mg/100mL
Levofloxacin 500mg
Procaterol Hydrochloride …………… 25μg
```

The first line, I want to just get 'mg' without 'mL' in my result.

The second line, I want get 'mg'.

The third line, I want get 'ug'.

I have try regexp pattern like:

```
(?!(.*[ ]{1}[0-9]+))[a-zA-Zμ]+
```

However, the first line always returns 'mg' with 'mL'...

How could I just acquire 'mg' with regexp?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: show what exactly should be matched

Comment: just only 'mg' (without 'mL')

Comment: Try [`^\D+\d+\K[a-z]+`](https://regex101.com/r/uJSwkZ/4)

Comment: Thanks for Gurman. It works^^
Please reply my question, and I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @auxo Solution posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment section, try this regex:

```
^\D*[\d.]+\K[a-zμ]+
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uJSwkZ/7)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the string
- `\D*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character that is not a digit
- `[\d.]+` - matches 1+ occurrences of any character that is a digit
- `\K` - removes what has been matched so far
- `[a-zμ]+` - this is what you want. This will contain the units like mg, ml appearing after the first number. If there are any other special characters like `μ`, you can add them too in this character list